# Upper-triangular loop idiom for Scala Lists

Tags: scala, nested-loops, functor

From my background in imperative programming, I'm accustomed to doing

```
for (i = 0;  i < 1000000;  i++) {
    for (j = i + 1;  j < 1000000;  j++) {
        doSomething(array[i], array[j])
    }
}
```

to examine all unique pairs in a million element array.  `doSomething` is some operation that yields trivial results on diagonal and symmetric or antisymmetric results off diagonal--- that's why I only want to work on the upper triangle.  (There's a minor variant of this where the `i == j` case is interesting; that's easy to fix.)

I find myself oddly stuck trying to do this in Scala.  I have a large `List` and want to do something to all the pairwise combinations, but

```
list.flatMap(x => list.map(y => doSomething(x, y))
```

includes all the redundant or trivial cases (a factor of two too much work) and

```
(0 until 1000000).flatMap({i =>
  (0 until 1000000).map({j =>
    doSomething(list(i), list(j))
  })
})
```

would be very wrong because Lists are not random access (a factor of N^2 too much work).  I could convert my `Lists` to `Arrays`, but that feels like it misses the point.  `Lists` are linked lists, so the `j + 1` element from my imperative example is only a step away from the `i` I'm currently examining.  I'm sure I could write an efficient upper-triangular loop over linked lists in C/Python/whatever.

I suppose I can just swallow the factor of two for now, but this is such a common situation to run into that it feels like there ought to be a nice solution to it.

Also, does this "upper-triangular loop" have a common name?  I couldn't find a good search string for it.

**Edit:** Here's an example of a bad solution:

```
list.zipWithIndex.flatMap({case (x, i) =>
  list.zipWithIndex.map({case (y, j) =>
    if (j > i)
      doSomething(x, y)
    else
      Nil
  })
})
```

because it still visits the unwanted nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to look at the [Vector](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector%24) data type, it allows for quick indexed based look up.

Also, there is a built in combinations method that will give you what it looks like you are looking for.

```
scala> (1 to 3).combinations(2).mkString(" ")
res1: String = Vector(1, 2) Vector(1, 3) Vector(2, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you!  `combinations` is what I was looking for.  I took a look at the Scala docs and the description is so brief that I'm not embarrassed I didn't find it before.

Comment: This is pretty cool, but it only works because we are working with (1 to 3). What if I want the combinations from a list with repeated values? Should I use that to index? I wanted to iterate like this using generators...

Comment: Vector(1,2,2,3).combinations(2).mkString(" ") will give you the expected results with duplicates.

Comment: If the expected results for Vector(1,1,1,1).combinations(2).toList is List(Vector(1, 1)), then ok. But not if you're expecting 6 items in that list.

Answer (score 5):

You can use pattern matching and tail recursion in the following way:

```
@tailrec def walk[T](list: Seq[T]): Unit =
  list match {
    case head :: tail =>
      tail.foreach(doSomething(head, _))
      walk(tail)
    case Nil =>
  }
```

Comment: Thanks!  While this is really clever, I'd rather use a built-in functor.  It may be how `combinations` is implemented internally.

Answer (score -1):

About this part of the question:

> Also, does this "upper-triangular loop" have a common name? I couldn't find a good search string for it.

The common name for "upper-triangular loop" is triangular matrix. (as described in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix))

> ... a triangular matrix is a special kind of square matrix. A square matrix is called lower triangular if all the entries above the main diagonal are zero. Similarly, a square matrix is called upper triangular if all the entries below the main diagonal are zero.